# Set of difficult equations to solve

Tags: linear-algebra

I still have no answer for the set of equations from

[4 points in 3-d space (one known and three unknown)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797763/4-points-in-3-d-space-one-known-and-three-unknown)

$ 
\begin{cases} {
  k^TA_1k =1 \\  
  k^TA_2k =1 \\  
  k^TA_3k =1} 
  \end{cases}
 $

$A_1, A_2, A_3    $ are given, 3-d vector $  k$ is to be found..

Maybe the set would be easier *?* to solve  if  we add additional condition for
such set of equations where $ B_i $ and $ d_i$ are given

$\begin{cases} {
  k^TB_{12}k =d_{12}^2 \\    
  k^TB_{13}k =d_{13}^2   \\ 
  k^TB_{23}k =d_{23}^2 }
 \end{cases} $

possible additional conditions..

(equilateral triangle)
$ d_{12}= d_{13}= d_{23} $

or  (right triangle)
$ d_{23}^2=d_{12}^2+d_{13}^2 $

or (right isosceles triangle)

$ \begin{cases} {d_{23}^2=d_{12}^2+d_{13}^2  \\
  d_{12}=d_{13}} 
  \end{cases} $

Any idea ? Any hint ?

Comment: If the $A$ are general matrices, the system describes the intersection of three general quadrics. If I am right, this can be reduced to the resolution of a single univariate polynomial of degree $8$.

Comment: Check "Using multivariate resultants to find the intersection of three quadric surfaces, EW Chionh, RN Goldman, JR Miller".

Comment: @Yves Yes, I suppose solution can be found from intersection of surfaces in 3-d space. Polynomial of degree 8 probably is too high because any solution has an equivalent with minus values, so 4 probably is enough, but how to transform this set to polynomial form? Additional conditions are providing something for simplicity of solution ?

Comment: Thank you, Yves. The paper is very interesting.

Comment: Your particular problem is known as the "3-point perspective" and has been addressed by Fischler and Bolles in "Random Sample Consensus: A Paradigm for Model Fitting with Applictions to Image Analysis and Automated Cartography". See Appendix A.

Comment: So if it has really the name it will be easier to find solution... from what I see  I suppose even if the set of equations looks simply solution is not quite simple...

Comment: Indeed, I doubt those equalities bring a simplification as they cannot reduce the number of solutions.

Comment: @Yves  Thank you. Yes, as I see Appendix A gives solution in closed form. Thank you. What stays is to contemplate whether for more regular triangles we could  obtain simpler solutions.

Comment: Maybe the really helping condition would be if we knew an orientation of the surface of the triangle...

Comment: I doubt that. Kwowing the order of the roots of a quartic doesn't help you solve it.

Comment: Knowing orientation could constrain solution to the only one. The only really searched parameter would be in fact distance from the known point to that surface. Having distance it is easy to obtain unknown coordinates.